# Firing off multiple Tasks asynchronously and waiting for them to complete

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a situation where I want to fire off a user-defined number of tasks asynchronously and wait for all of them to complete.  Simplified, here's what I'm dealing with:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Start() {
        var numDrivers = 2;
        while (numDrivers != 0) {
            var rnd = new Random();
            var r = rnd.Next(itemArray.Count);
            var target = itemArray[r];
            var proxyDriver = GetProxiedDriver();
            Task.Run(() => HandleIntro(proxyDriver, target));
            numDrivers--;
        }
 }
```

For some context - these are Selenium webdrivers getting spun up to run some UI tests.  I see the browsers pop up, but as soon as the last `Task.Run()` completes, all execution stops.  How do I fire off `n` drivers to run asynchronously while waiting for them all to complete before stopping execution?

I've tried `await Task.Run(() => HandleIntro(proxyDriver, target));` but this awaits the task and they don't run simultaneously.

**HandleIntro:**

```
private async Task HandleIntro(FirefoxDriver driver, string target) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: You can use `Task.WhenAll` on an array of `Task`s, and `await` that.

Comment: Look into `Task.WaitAll()`/`WhenAll()`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's rather simple with `async-await`. You have [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which itself returns an awaitable which can be asynchronously waited for all tasks to complete:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Start() 
{
   var numDrivers = 2;
   List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

   while (numDrivers != 0) 
   {
       var rnd = new Random();
       var r = rnd.Next(itemArray.Count);

       var target = itemArray[r];
       var proxyDriver = GetProxiedDriver();

       tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => HandleIntro(proxyDriver, target)));
       numDrivers--;
   }

   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... execution stops immediately with this too, test passes as soon as the first one starts up

Comment: Perhaps an exception is thrown inside `HandleIntro`? Set CLR Exceptions on and see.

Comment: I'm a dummy, mistyped something.  Thanks so much :)